# Limit of this sequence: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n\right)$

Tags: limits, radicals

So guys I need to find the limit of:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n\right)$

The quadratic equation is hard to factorise and I really struggle to answer these questions.

Do I need to use the limit comparison test after I simplify this?

Comment: What does limit from $n=1$ mean? Do you mean summation instead?

Comment: There is a standard trick involving square roots and something called the conjugate. Are you familiar with it? (Also, do you mean the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} ...$ instead?)

Comment: Anyway I doubt that the limit comparison test will help you if you wnat to exactly evaluate the value of the sequence/sum for $n=\infty$

Comment: @T.Bongers But that would diverge, no?

Comment: @T.Bongers Well, $\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n>\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}-n=(n+1)-n=1$, so the summation would diverge because each term is greater than $1$.

Comment: @KennyLau But at the moment we still don't know what the OP is interested in. The series sum or the sequence?

Comment: Its the sequence itself I am reffering to not the sum

Comment: Multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}+n$ is almost automatic here. There are other ways worth exploring, however.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040/201168)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720211/how-do-i-find-undersetx-rightarrow-infty-lima-x-x-sqrtx2-4x/1720353#1720353  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632157/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n/1632163#1632163

Comment: Amongst tons of copies or nearly copies on the site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45970/evaluating-lim-limits-x-to-infty-sqrt6x6x5-sqrt6x6-x5/

Comment: @T.Bongers Suppose I had to find the limit of the summation, how would I do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

When you're facing a limit that's difference of square roots (or any radical indeed) it's a nice idea is to multiply by the sum of the two square roots. So we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + 2n + 5} - n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 + 2n + 5 - n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}+n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 + \frac 5n}{\sqrt{1 + \frac 2n + \frac 5{n^2}} + 1} = 1$$

Comment: Should i delete my answer ? just posted a 1 minute after you and found out that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @ritwiksinha I leave it up to you. I mean I don't own any copyrights to this answer after all. ;)

Comment: I will wait till i receive a down vote. :)

Comment: Thanks that helped alot, now suppose I had to find the limit of the sum of the sequence, what would I have to do differently?

Comment: @MooeSha123 Well, if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5} - n\right)$ converges then $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5} - n\right) = 0$. But as this is not true the series is divergent. In fact $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt{n^2+2n+5} - n\right) \approx \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$

Comment: If you put in n=1 rather than where you put n=0, would that make a difference?

Comment: @MooeSha123 Not at all. If we add or subtract **finately** many **finite** terms to the sequence that wouldn't change the convergence/divergence of the series.

Comment: And how about the limit for the summation sequence?

Comment: @MooeSha123 Summation sequence? I don't get the question

Comment: The limit of the sequence itself. Is is infinity?

Comment: @MooeSha123 What sequence? We proved that the limit of the sequence in your question is $1$.

Comment: No I mean the sum sequence as in what you were referring to in your last line when I asked for the limit of the sum of sequence.

Comment: @MooeSha123 I recommend you to close this question by selecting an answer and what you asked is already answered.

Comment: @MooeSha123 if $a_{n + 1} - a_{n} \lt 1$ only then the series will converge, else not.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n^2 + 2n +5} - n) \cdot \frac{(\sqrt{n^2 + 2n +5} + n)}{(\sqrt{n^2 + 2n +5} + n)}
 &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n +5}{(\sqrt{n^2 + 2n +5} + n)}\\
 &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 +{5\over n}}{(\sqrt{1 + {2\over n} +{5\over n^2}} + 1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{(1 + 1)} = 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n
&=n(\sqrt{1+2/n+5/n^2}-1)\\
&= n((1+(2/n+5/n^2)/2+O(1/n^2))-1)\\
&= n(1/n+5/(2n^2)+O(1/n^2))\\
&= 1+5/(2n)+O(1/n)\\
&\to 1
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}+n$ is almost automatic here, and is the "right" way to proceed.  But let us take another approach. Note that 
$$n^2+2n+5=(n+1)^2+4\gt (n+1)^2.$$
Also,
$$(n+1)^2+4\lt \left(n+1+\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^2.$$
This inequality is easy to verify by squaring $n+1+\frac{2}{n+1}$.
Thus
$$1\lt \sqrt{n^2+2n+5}-n\lt 1+\frac{2}{n+1}.$$
So by Squeezing our limit is $1$.

*Remark:* The above is a formal version of the observation that for $n$ large, $\sqrt{(n+1)^2+4}$ is "almost" equal to $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

A round-about but fun/elementary approach. Note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n^{2}+2n+5}-n & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n\left(n+2\right)+5}-n\\
 & =\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\left(m-1\right)\left(m+1\right)+5}-\left(m-1\right)\\
 & =\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{m^{2}+4}-m+1
\end{align*}
so that it is enough to consider
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{m^{2}+4}-m.
$$
Clearly, for $m\geq0$, the expression under the limit is positive.
Let $\epsilon>0$, and note that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{m^{2}+4}-m<\epsilon & \iff\sqrt{m^{2}+4}<\epsilon+m\\
 & \iff m^{2}+4<\left(\epsilon+m\right)^{2}\\
 & \iff m^{2}+4<\epsilon^{2}+2\epsilon m+m^{2}\\
 & \iff0<\epsilon^{2}+2\epsilon m-4.
\end{align*}
Clearly, we can pick $m$ large enough so that this is true, and hence
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{m^{2}+4}-m=0
$$
so that the original limit is $1$.